# Want to get to know how many times double 6 appeared while rolling the dice to randomly generated number of time?

Tags: python-3.x

I just saved the results as string and now performing the check using the loop but its not working
counter is still 0 if 66 appeared in the result.

```
from random import *

trial = int(randint(1, 10))
print(trial)
result = ''
for i in range(trial):
    init_num = str(randint(1, 6))
    result += init_num
print(result)

last_dice = 0
counter = 0
for i in range(trial):
    if result[i] == 6 and last_dice == 6:
        counter += 1
        last_dice = 0
    else:
        last_dice = result[i]

print(counter)
```

Comment: `trial = int(randint(1, 10))` sets a random number of dice rolls to between 1 and 10. Let's say it is 5. However, double "6" only happens about once in 36 rolls. So first thing is to increase this to `trial = int(randint(1, 1000))`. Then also make the fix  offered by @fuzzydrawings realted to testing int vs str.

Answer (score 1):

> `if result[i] == 6`

This condition will never be true because the value in 'result' is a string. If you change the `6` to `'6'` it should work.

### EDIT

*"how many time double 6 appeared while rolling the dice"* implies the dice are being rolled in pairs. As it is, your script will count any two consecutive sixes as having been rolled together. For example if the rolls are 4,6,6,5 your script counts this as an instance of double sixes, **which is not accurate if the rolls are occurring in pairs**. For this reason you should generate the random 1-6 values in pairs so it is clear when sixes are actually rolled together.

You could create 'results' as a list where each item is a pair of numbers representing a roll of two dice:

```py
results = [str(randint(1,6))+str(randint(1,6)) for i in range(randint(1, 10))]
```

Your 'trials' variable is only used to print the number of rolls. If each roll is for a pair of dice, the number of rolls is equal to the number of items in the above 'results' list. Printing this value doesn't require a variable, but merely the length of the list:

```py
print(len(results))
```

One way to print all the roll results is as an easily readable string of comma-separated roll pair values, which can be done printing this list joined together with each item separated by a comma:

```py
print(','.join(results))
```

Counting the number of double sixes rolled can be done by summing the number of times the value '66' appears in the 'results' list:

```py
print(sum(i == '66' for i in results))
```

All together the script could be written as:

```py
from random import randint

results = [str(randint(1,6))+str(randint(1,6)) for i in range(randint(1, 10))]
print(len(results))
print(','.join(results))
print(sum(i == '66' for i in results))
```

Comment: I read the question as asking only why double sixes are not being counted when they appeared in the result.

Comment: His script includes printing the result string, so he sees if there are two sixes in it or not.